# JSON deserialization - Map array indices to properties with JSON.NET

Tags: c#, arrays, json, json.net

I want to deserialize a 2-dimensional array to a collection of .net objects. The reason is, array syntax will be easier for my user to work with in an input file. So I just want to map the indices of the arrays to specific properties of my target type.

E.G. With:

```
[
     ["John", "Smith", "23"],
     ["Paula", "Martin", "54]
]
```

I would get two instances of a Person:

```
public class Person {
    public string First {get;set;}
    public string Last {get;set;}
    public string Age {get;set;}
}
```

where index 0 of an inner array maps to `First`, index 1 maps to `Last`, and index 2 maps to `Age`;

Is there a way to extend Json.NET so that I can do the mapping during deserialization so the implementation details are hidden? I have been playing around with a custom `JsonConverter` but I haven't found much info on how to use it.

Edit:
Specifically, I'm not sure if `JsonConverter` is the right thing to use, and I'm having trouble figuring out how to implement `CanConvert` and how to use the parameters passed to the `ReadJson` method.

Comment: Looks like something I'd try to do - but I would suggest that in the end, youll just end up using standard json. The fieldnames must be repeated for each 'Person', but it's a small price.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do this with a [`JsonConverter`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm).  A simple converter for this purpose would be:

```
public class PersonConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(Person);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
            return null;
        var array = JArray.Load(reader);
        var person = (existingValue as Person ?? new Person());
        person.First = (string)array.ElementAtOrDefault(0);
        person.Last = (string)array.ElementAtOrDefault(1);
        person.Age = (string)array.ElementAtOrDefault(2);
        return person;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var person = (Person)value;
        serializer.Serialize(writer, new[] { person.First, person.Last, person.Age });
    }
}
```

If the specific properties have non-primitive types, you can use [`JToken.ToObject<T>(JsonSerializer)`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_ToObject__1_1.htm) to deserialize them to the required type:

```
person.First = array.ElementAtOrDefault(0)?.ToObject<string>(serializer);
```

Then you can apply it to your class:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(PersonConverter))]
public class Person
{
    public string First { get; set; }
    public string Last { get; set; }
    public string Age { get; set; }
}
```

Or use it in settings:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings { Converters = new [] { new PersonConverter() } };
var list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Person>>(json, settings);
```

Comment: This seems like it's on the right track, but it appears to only handle a single Person array, not an array of Person arrays. I'll mark as an answer for confirming a JsonConverter can do it. See my answer for the implementation I came up with. Please let me know if you see any problems with it.

Answer (score 5):

For a general purpose converter, here's an implementation that uses attributes to associate the properties:

```cs
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Field, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class JsonArrayIndexAttribute : Attribute
{
    public JsonArrayIndexAttribute(int index)
    {
        Index = index;
    }
    
    public int Index { get; }
}

public class JsonArrayConverter<T> : JsonConverter<T>
{
    public override T? ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, T? existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        switch (reader.TokenType)
        {
            case JsonToken.StartArray:
                var members = GetIndexedMembers(objectType);
                var arr = JArray.ReadFrom(reader);
                var fromArray = hasExistingValue ? existingValue! : Activator.CreateInstance<T>()!;
                foreach (var (member, value) in members.Zip(arr))
                {
                    member.setter?.Invoke(fromArray, Convert.ChangeType(value, member.type));
                }
                return fromArray;
            case JsonToken.StartObject:
                var fromObject = hasExistingValue ? existingValue! : Activator.CreateInstance<T>()!;
                serializer.Populate(reader, fromObject);
                return fromObject;
            case JsonToken.Null:
                return default;
            case JsonToken.Undefined:
                return hasExistingValue ? existingValue : default;
            default:
                throw new JsonSerializationException($"Unexpected TokenType: {reader.TokenType}");
        }
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, T? value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            writer.WriteNull();
            return;
        }
        var members = GetIndexedMembers(value.GetType());
        writer.WriteStartArray();
        foreach (var member in members)
        {
            writer.WriteValue(member.getter?.Invoke(value));
        }
        writer.WriteEndArray();
    }
    
    private IEnumerable<(Type? type, Func<object, object?>? getter, Action<object, object?>? setter)> GetIndexedMembers(Type type)
    {
        var indexedMembers =
            (from member in type.GetMembers()
            let index = (JsonArrayIndexAttribute?)member.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(JsonArrayIndexAttribute))
            where index != null
            select (member, index.Index))
            .ToLookup(x => x.Index, x => x.member);

        return
            (from i in Enumerable.Range(0, indexedMembers.Max(x => x.Key) + 1)
            from m in indexedMembers[i].TakeLast(1).DefaultIfEmpty()
            select CreateAccessors(m));
            
        (Type, Func<object, object?>?, Action<object, object?>?) CreateAccessors(MemberInfo m) => m switch
        {
            PropertyInfo p => (p.PropertyType, obj => p.GetValue(obj), (obj, value) => p.SetValue(obj, value)),
            FieldInfo f => (f.FieldType, obj => f.GetValue(obj), (obj, value) => f.SetValue(obj, value)),
            _ => default,
        };
    }
}
```

Then to use it in your case:

```cs
[JsonConverter(typeof(JsonArrayConverter<Person>))]
public class Person
{
    [JsonArrayIndex(0)]
    public string First { get; set; } = default!;
    
    [JsonArrayIndex(1)]
    public string Last { get; set; } = default!;
    
    [JsonArrayIndex(2)]
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This should be added into System.Text.Json !!!!!!!!

Comment: I've adapted your solution to `System.Text.Json` in my own answer below.

Comment: I don't think it would be as useful to be added to the base framework. Serializing an object as an array is not a common thing. It might be more useful generally for types that can be deconstructed to tuples however.

Comment: Javascript "tuples" i.e. arrays of fixed structure are not a rare thing, and definitely worth creating a general case for.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        if (objectType == typeof(List<Person>)) return true;

        return false;
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        List<Person> persons = new List<Person>();

        JArray personsArray = (JArray)serializer.Deserialize(reader);

        foreach (var personArray in personsArray.Children<JArray>())
        {
            persons.Add(new Person() { 
                         First = personArray[0].Value<string>(),
                         Last = personArray[1].Value<string>(),
                         Age = personArray[2].Value<string>()
                        });
        }

        return persons;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've adapted the [general solution by Jeff Mercado](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67452768/235648) (in another answer to this question)
which was written for Newtonsoft into a `System.Text.Json` compatible solution:

```cs
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Field)]
public class JsonArrayIndexAttribute(int index) : Attribute {
    public int Index { get; } = index;
}

public class JsonArrayConverter<T> : JsonConverter<T> {
    private static readonly IndexedPropertyDescriptor NoOperation =
        new(typeof(object), _ => null, (_, _) => { });

    public override T Read(
        ref Utf8JsonReader reader,
        Type typeToConvert,
        JsonSerializerOptions options
    ) {
        var returnedObject =
            Activator.CreateInstance(typeToConvert) ??
            throw new JsonException($"Couldn't create object of type {typeToConvert}");

        var members = GetIndexedMembers(typeToConvert);
        foreach (var member in members) {
            reader.Read();

            if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.EndArray) {
                // Return early if array ends before all members have been assigned
                return (T)returnedObject;
            }

            var parsedValue = JsonSerializer.Deserialize(
                reader: ref reader,
                returnType: member.Type,
                options: options);

            member.Setter(returnedObject, parsedValue);
        }

        // Eat up the rest of the elements, if any.
        while (true) {
            reader.Read();
            if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.EndArray) {
                break;
            }

            _ = JsonSerializer.Deserialize(
                reader: ref reader,
                returnType: typeof(object),
                options: options);
        }

        return (T)returnedObject;
    }

    public override void Write(
        Utf8JsonWriter writer,
        T value,
        JsonSerializerOptions options
    ) {
        if (value is null) {
            writer.WriteNullValue();
            return;
        }

        writer.WriteStartArray();
        var members = GetIndexedMembers(typeof(T));
        foreach (var member in members) {
            var sourceValue = member.Getter(value);
            JsonSerializer.Serialize(
                writer: writer,
                value: sourceValue,
                inputType: member.Type,
                options: options);
        }

        writer.WriteEndArray();
    }

    private static IEnumerable<IndexedPropertyDescriptor>
        GetIndexedMembers(Type type) {
        var indexedMembers = (
                from member in type.GetMembers()
                let index = (JsonArrayIndexAttribute?)member
                    .GetCustomAttribute(typeof(JsonArrayIndexAttribute))
                where index != null
                select (member, index.Index))
            .ToLookup(x => x.Index, x => x.member);

        var max = indexedMembers.Count == 0 
            ? 0 
            : indexedMembers.Max(x => x.Key) + 1;

        return
            from i in Enumerable.Range(0, max)
            from m in indexedMembers[i].TakeLast(1).DefaultIfEmpty()
            select CreateAccessors(m);

        IndexedPropertyDescriptor CreateAccessors(MemberInfo m) => m switch {
            PropertyInfo p =>
                new(Type: p.PropertyType,
                    Getter: obj => p.GetValue(obj),
                    Setter: (obj, value) => p.SetValue(obj, value)),
            FieldInfo f =>
                new(Type: f.FieldType,
                    Getter: obj => f.GetValue(obj),
                    Setter: (obj, value) => f.SetValue(obj, value)),
            _ => NoOperation,
        };
    }

    private record IndexedPropertyDescriptor(
        Type Type,
        Func<object, object?> Getter,
        Action<object, object?> Setter);
}
```

Usage remains the same as in Jeff's answer:

```cs
[JsonConverter(typeof(JsonArrayConverter<Person>))]
public class Person
{
    [JsonArrayIndex(0)]
    public string First { get; set; } = default!;
    
    [JsonArrayIndex(1)]
    public string Last { get; set; } = default!;
    
    [JsonArrayIndex(2)]
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```