# How to consume API response of array without property names - C#

Tags: c#

I need to consume an API service which returns the following. The object does not contain property names, there for I am not clear what the model or for each loop should look like. Please advise. Thanks

```
            {
              "0": [
                [
                  "01:08 PM - 01:28 PM",
                  "2017-07-19T13:08:24.000-07:00",
                  218
                ],
            [
              "01:23 PM - 01:43 PM",
              "2017-07-19T13:23:24.000-07:00",
              218
            ],
            [
              "01:38 PM - 01:58 PM",
              "2017-07-19T13:38:24.000-07:00",
              218
            ],
            [
              "01:53 PM - 02:13 PM",
              "2017-07-19T13:53:24.000-07:00",
              218
            ],
            [
              "02:08 PM - 02:28 PM",
              "2017-07-19T14:08:24.000-07:00",
              218
            ],
            [
              "02:23 PM - 02:43 PM",
              "2017-07-19T14:23:24.000-07:00",
              218
            ],
            [
              "12:53 PM - 01:13 PM",
              "2017-07-19T12:53:24.000-07:00",
              218
            ]
          ]
        }
```

Comment: It has a property name: `"0"` - and that contains an array of arrays

Comment: Why the negative sign on my question. I didn't author the API, I just have to consume it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use an json to c# converter, it yields this:

```
public class RootObject
{
    public List<List<object>> __invalid_name__0 { get; set; }
}
```

Unfortunately, 0 is not an allowed proerty name in C#
You can use newtonsoft JSON to map the property to a different name:

```
public class RootObject
{
   [JsonProperty("0")]
    public List<List<object>> zero { get; set; }
}
```

But that yields an extremely unwieldy construct

Probably this would be better:

```
public class RootObject
{
   [JsonProperty("0")]
    public List<InnerObj> zero { get; set; }
}

public class InnerObj
{
    public string Range { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
}
```

To deserialize this, see this question: [JSON deserialization - Map array indices to properties with JSON.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36757412/json-deserialization-map-array-indices-to-properties-with-json-net)

Comment: Thanks. I did try json2sharp converter first and didn't help. I will give what you have a shot.

Answer (score -1):

Based on Christian's answer, this is what I am going to go with:

```
public class Times
{
    [JsonProperty("0")]
    public List<TimeObject> times { get; set; }
}

public class TimeObject
{
    public string Range { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
}
```

}